# Grouping of Selenium Chrome windows in Windows 10 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a Python programme that will log in to a site and monitor some information continuously. I have multiple accounts which I am planning to launch as multiple sessions. I have created an executable for my programme to make it more smooth to use.

Right now, I am having a setup that saves cookies to a `user-data-dir` to save login info so that I don't have to put it in every time. I am trying to switch to a method where I can load login info from a file thus stopping the use of `user-data-dir`.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=userdata")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("URL")
```

This is my existing setup with a folder with user-data. In this, when I am running multiple sessions of the same programme, the new windows are getting opened as a group in the taskbar. (Marked in red in the image.)

```
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
```

I am trying to change the code to this, and the code is working as expected. But the grouping of the Windows has stopped, they are now getting opened with different icons in taskbar.(Marked in blue in the image).

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this? I want them to be opened inside a single group.[image: The picture, both the scenarios are shown, the red is the first and the blue second.]

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this because each Selenium launch browser will be a new and individual process. The only thing you can do is to launch it in a headless mode so it doesn't even show up

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Then why is it that I didn't have the issue when my code looked like this?
`options = Options()`
`options.add_argument("user-data-dir=userdata")`
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`
`driver.get("URL")`

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. For you should target one profile per one unique login you want to track, in case you want things to be in parallel. If it is ok for you to use things sequentially within the same browser then you can use one profile and you should not relaunch the browser again and again

Comment: I want it to be in parallel, so could you tell me more about the ** target one profile per one unique login you want to track**, I want to have all logins in parallel, and also want the icons in the taskbar to be grouped. I am not very clear about the idea you mentioned.

Comment: Parallel and grouped cannot go together. Selenium or Chrome API lets you work on one tab at a time. So for parallel you will have to launch multiple chromes and use headless option to hide the icon all together. Also for multiple profiles you will use something like `options.add_argument("user-data-dir=userdata1")`, `options.add_argument("user-data-dir=userdata2")`